# Good Core Data Example Code with Subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am having an issue with my Core Data app and I could probably figure it out if I could look at a good example. I have searched the web and I have only been able to find the same examples like Random Dates which is pretty much useless and only has one View Controller. I am looking for a Core Data app using multiple levels and real information, not random date inserts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Marc Zarra, Core Data guru, has some helpful blog posts that might get you a little bit closer. Try [starting here](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/01/07/passing-around-a-nsmanagedobjectcontext-on-the-iphone) to get you started. This is just one way to go about it. I'm using a shared managed object context via a shared instance of my app controller, so all I have to do is call something like this from a view controller to start accessing my CD object:

```
    AppController *ac = [AppController sharedAppController];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [ac managedObjectContext];
```

I can't find the relevant links right now, but I have a feeling that idea might have come out of the Big Nerd Ranch iPhone dev book. I hope this helps get you going on the right path for what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out. It is the one Core Data book I haven't bought yet.